# How to delete blank space in crystal report

Tags: asp.net, .net, visual-studio, crystal-reports, report

[image: Crystal Report Image]

Based on the image I posted above, how do I remove the blank space between the `GroupHeaderSection1` and `GroupHeaderSection2`. I just want to remove the empty white space below the row that has names `Bar Mark`, `Type&Size` and etc.

Comment: Right click on "groupheadersection1" and click on fit "section".

Comment: @Mahendra Hi i already tried to click on the fit section checkbox, but when i want to print it, the output preview in the printer option, it does not remove the empty spaces.

Comment: suppress the section which are empty

Comment: @Mahendra How to suppress the section which are empty? Do i have to right click the groupheadersection1 and then click on section expert. Then tick on the checkbox Suppress blank section?

Comment: Don't Suppress Groupheadersection1  suppress Groupheadersection2,3,4 right click on section and suppress

Comment: @Mahendra For groupheadersection 2,3 and 4 i have already tick the box suppress blank section. After that for groupheadersection 1 i click on fit section. but still in the preview print, the empty space is there. When i print the dot matrix. The gap is still there

Comment: Insert new section below Groupheadersection1 and then move the header to the new section and then fit section of both Groupheadersection1

Comment: is there any subreport in header section

Comment: Right click on Groupheadersection1 then select insert section below

Comment: It creates GroupHeaderSection5 which is located above GroupHeaderSection2. Above GroupHeaderSection5 there is still gap like the usual

Comment: gap is below or the GroupHeaderSection5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Move the selected part to below section as shown in image and then fit section]

Move the selected part to below section as shown in figure and then fit section

Comment: Is there any subreport or can grow text object in group section 1